# Working with AVKit AVPlayerViewController

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, avplayer, avkit

I want to know more about `AVPlayerViewController` from `AVKit`,like its delegate methods and all. I read about it from [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerViewController_Class/index.html), but I don't understand it. Can anybody provide some other links,tutorials or sample code for the same.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to learn about a component in iOS are [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerViewController_Class/index.html) itself, you should try and follow Apple docs. [Here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IOS_8_Video_Playback_using_AVPlayer_and_AVPlayerViewController) is a short tutorial on playing video using `AVPlayerViewController`.

Although, you can find a sample project of `AVPlayerViewController` [here](https://github.com/mdejong/SunSpot).

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you start with some actual working AVPlayerViewController source code and go from there. It is easier than just looking at Apple docs. I wrote up [this blog post](http://www.modejong.com/blog/post13_iOS8_SunSpot/index.html) showing a video of the Sun compiled from NASA sources. A link to the github source is included and you can checkout and run the example easily.